# Dynamic buttons background-color changes at same time when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, button

Created a small project in vuejs to understand how binding works with classes and style and so on.
The behavior I wanted is that when clicking on different dynamic buttons they should have different backgrounds and it works partially. The issue is when I clicked on one button the other buttons also change their background-color at the same time and I don't want this behavior.
I have `active props`  and I think it's causing this issue.

`DynamicButton.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="btn1">
      <button
        v-on="$listeners"
        :class="[dark ? 'dark' : 'light', 'baseButton']"
        class="btn"
        :style="{ backgroundColor: color }"
      >
        {{ buttonText }}
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "DynamicButton",

  props: {
    buttonText: {
      type: String,
      default: "label",
    },
    dark: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },

    light: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true,
    },
    active: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    color: {
      type: String,
      default: "gray",
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.baseButton {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
}

.light {
  background: white;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}

.dark {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.btn {
  margin: 10px;
}
</style>
```

`app.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png" />
   
    <DynamicButton
      buttonText="Dark Mode"
      :dark="true"
      @click="handleDarkMode"
      :color="active ? 'red' : 'blue'"
    />
   
    <DynamicButton
      buttonText="Light Mode"
      @click="handleLightMode"
      :color="active ? this.color : '#16a085'"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import DynamicButton from "./components/DynamicButton.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
    DynamicButton,
  },

  props: {
    // darkColorChange: {
    //   type: String,
    //   default: "",
    // },
    // lightColorChange: {
    //   type: String,
    //   default: "",
    // },
  },

  data() {
    return {
      active: true,
      color: "#3aa1b6",
    };
  },

  methods: {
    handleDarkMode() {
      console.log("Dark-mode clicked");
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      // this.darkColorChange.style.backgroundColor = "pink";
      this.active = !this.active;
    },

    handleLightMode() {
      console.log("Light-mode clicked");
      this.active = !this.active;
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

my buttons Components

[image]

Comment: You are using one variable for two components

Comment: Yes you need two `active` state to control

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the same variable `active` for two different components, so it's only normal that both components would react the same way.

I would go for two different variables or an array of objects, containing the data for all the buttons because you may have more buttons in the future.

Comment: Thanks, can you show some example so it will be easy to proceed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).